# Change active page in tabbed notebook using shortcut keys;

Tags: delphi, events, global

Delphi v7. I am learning a lot here. People are so willing to help. So, I have yet another question.

I would like to change the active page of a tabbed notebook using shortcut keys. I can do it in a keydown event inside a control, but it doesn't save any time having to click inside a control than it does clicking the tabs on the notebook.

Example Delphi7:

```
procedure TForm1.Edit2KeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  Shift: TShiftState);
begin
 if (ssCtrl in Shift) and (Upcase(Chr(key)) = 'T') then
   tabNB.PageIndex:= tabNB.PageIndex +1;
end;
```

The goal is to be able to use shortcut keys without having to do it inside a control's keydown event. Is it possible to write a procedure in some global area of the project that would allow me to do that?

Comment: What is the reason you are using a TabbedNotebook instead of a PageControl? TabbedNotebook is even on the `Win 3.1` page?

Comment: By the way, the first generalisation would be to use Form1's OnKeyDown handler. You will have to set Form1's KeyPreview property to True for that to work. And set Key to `0` when you have handled it and now want it to be ignored by others.

Comment: I recommend "TJvWizard" from JVCL. Only for the possibility of navigating through the pages in design time without change the .DFM file, it would be worthwhile. But, of course, it is better than TabbedNotebook in many other aspects.

Answer (score 0):

you can use tips in [How to set up hot key](http://delphi.about.com/cs/adptips2001/a/bltip0601_3.htm)

or You can use TJvApplicationHotKey component from JVCL Jedi library (free), drop it on your form, set the Hotkey property, set active property to true, and put your code

```
tabNB.PageIndex:= tabNB.PageIndex +1;
```

in onHotKey event.

By the way, TNoteBook is an old component, you can use TPageControl as a replacement.

Comment: I can see that TPageControl would have been a better choice. I didn't think of it, because I don't know how to use it. I will give it a try though. As for the tabbed notebook on this project putting it into the form's keydown event works great - Thanks

Comment: Glad to know that @Robert. Yeah true, using form's keydown event is simpler :).

Comment: So, I created a test project with page control. I must be stupid. It was so easy to manipulate. This place is great!!  I have learned a lot here. Thank you all.